# Update one updatePanel without Updating the other?

Tags: updatepanel, ajax.net

I have two updatePanels, each with a label and a button.  I want to click on button 1 and it updates label 2, without updating/refreshing updatePanel 1 at all. Is this doable?  Because button 1 is in updatePanel 1, updatePanel always seems to refresh.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this will fix your problem: http://jalpesh.blogspot.com/2010/12/programmatically-updating-one-update.html

Comment: For some odd reason, my updatePanel 1 keeps updating on its own, even though I didn't call the update() method.

Comment: That would be cool if you share source code with us somewhere